# Prepare function doesn't call by segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

In my swift app I've this functions, I'll not specify the class because it's not important.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? LocalTVC,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.selectedLocal = favouriteLocals[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    func presentLocalTVC() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "localTVCID") as! LocalTVC
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.presentLocalTVC()
}
```

But when the tableViewControlller, LocalTVC, is presented the variables "selectedLocal" is nil.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using segues, you should use [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue)
 You are using [`present(_:animated:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) which is independant of storyboard delegates.

Comment: Thank you, And how can I do that if my views are in two differents storyboard files?

Comment: @MarioJ add a storyboard reference

Comment: "...which is independant of storyboard delegates" What does that mean? Don't you mean to say "...which is independant of storyboard segues?"